# Is there any flash driver at the OS level loaded?

Tags: linux, flash-memory

whether Is there any flash driver at the OS level (linux) to load or we need to write/develop ?, please suggest me.

Comment: Do you mean flash memory, or Adobe flash? The mention of "driver" hints at the former, but the "flash" tag suggests the latter. Confusing.

Comment: Sorry, am asking about flash memory

Comment: There are drivers for USB FLASH cards, for MTD etc. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Is there a particular CF reader that you are having a problem with?

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a connection scenario where Linux would *not* see the media. Additionally, I can't see a scenario involving a file system on it that was not supported.

What remains is how your kernel was compiled. Without additional information, I can only say it *should* work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Flash readers connected via USB are handled by the `usb-storage` driver. Readers connected via another bus (e.g. PCI) need a separate MTD driver in order to be recognized. The Linux kernel comes with a number of them, but there will always be some that aren't (yet) supported.

Comment: There are CF -> IDE, CF -> SATA, CF -> SCSI and CF -> Firewire adapters floating around. Its hard to tell what he has.

Comment: @Tim: There are more types of flash memory than CompactFlash.

Answer (score 1):

*My mistake. I thought the OP was referring to Adobe Flash as he gave no indication in the original question that he meant Flash Memory Hardware.*

It isn't an OS "driver" but there is a [Linux version of Flash player 10.1](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer10.html) which will allow you to run flash resources within your OS as you normally would of the Windows version.

I suspect you might be confused about the word driver within the context of an OS and that the Player is actually what you're looking for.